# Короткая запись условия в PHP 7.1

Tags: php

Есть стандартное условие на существование и не пустоту переменной:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']) and !empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
        
        
        
}
```

Так же условие можно записать в одну строку:

```
isset($_SESSION['user']) and !empty($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : false;
```

Вопрос:

Как реализовать данную проверку в одну сроку в php 7.1? Я знаю есть более короткий вариант но не могу найти правильное решение.

Comment: как минимум использование empty в связке с isset не имеет смысла..... почему? см. документацию... а условия для if коротко нельзя записать.....есть оператор `??`  и `?=`  но это не про `if`

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = $var ?? "default";
```

И еще если вы проверяете на empty() то проверка на isset() выполняется уже автоматически и смысла не имеет.

Comment: В случае если переменная например такая $var['user'] и мне нужно проверить существует ли она и не пуста ли она.

Comment: if(!empty($var['user']){  //код тут } - проверки на empty() достаточно, это включает проверку на isset(). Более короткая запись ?? применяется когда вам надо сразу же достать значение переменной и куда-то присвоить.